# Pre ico and ico crowdsale contracts

Tags: ico, crowdsale

Can you please recommend the best way to organize pre-ICO and ICO using Etherium smart contracts.

I have found two options:

**1)** To make 2 different contracts and after ICO merge them (pre-ICO with ICO contract)

**2)** To make 2 different crowdsale contracts with different hard cap and different time but with the same token name

Comment: good question. I don't understand why it's on hold. I'm thinking about the same question at the moment. @ace-flinston did you make any research on the topic, how icos did it before?